# Azure Nuxt not found

Tags: azure, nuxt.js

I've a problem when I generate a website in Node.js

I've a WebApp On Linux, the Pipeline success, the release success, but when I go to the site, returns

:( Application Error

Looking in the logs, returns "Nuxt not found".

What's the problem?

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt -o",
    "dev:e2e": "cypress open",
    "build": "nuxt build --modern",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate --modern",
    "generate:dev": "cross-env ENV_DEV=true nuxt generate --modern",
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --fix",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint --fix",
    "lint:markdownlint": "markdownlint",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --write --loglevel warn",
    "lint:all:eslint": "yarn lint:eslint --ext .js,.vue .",
    "lint:all:stylelint": "yarn lint:stylelint \"**/*.{vue,scss}\"",
    "lint:all:markdownlint": "yarn lint:markdownlint \"docs/*.md\" \"*.md\"",
    "lint:all:prettier": "yarn lint:prettier \"**/*.{js,json,css,scss,vue,html,md}\"",
    "lint": "run-s lint:all:*",
    "new": "hygen new"
  },
```

If I try with a blobstorage it's ok, but I can't make the root domain go to the Blobstorage (example.com) because need a CNAME.

Comment: Does it work if you generate it locally (btw, how do you try it)? Also, could you share your `nuxt.config.js` file? Did you followed one of the 2 Azure deployments listed here? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-azure-static-web-apps

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**

Try to add startup command. If it doesn't work, try method 2.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

or

Usually use it in Angular Project.

```
npx serve -s
```

**Method 2.**

Use copy below code and paste it to package.json. Then tell me the result.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build --modern",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate --modern",
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --fix",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint --fix",
    "lint:markdownlint": "markdownlint",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --write --loglevel warn",
    "lint:all:eslint": "yarn lint:eslint --ext .js,.vue .",
    "lint:all:stylelint": "yarn lint:stylelint \"**/*.{vue,scss}\"",
    "lint:all:markdownlint": "yarn lint:markdownlint \"docs/*.md\" \"*.md\"",
    "lint:all:prettier": "yarn lint:prettier \"**/*.{js,json,css,scss,vue,html,md}\"",
    "lint": "run-s lint:all:*",
    "new": "hygen new"
 },
```

In `nuxt.config.js`.

```
server: {
    port:  process.env.PORT, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
},
```

How to deploy nuxt(nuxt.js) in azure(web app)? (not found module)

Answer (score 0):

It's solved

The problem was in the release.

WebApp Service is in PHP 7.4, so, the release (Job Azure Service Deploy) in the dropdown "Runtime Stack" needs to be in PHP 7.4